# Proving a language is regular through the reverse language

Tags: automata, regular-language

Consider the language $L$ with symbols that can be written from the alphabet
$$ \Sigma = \left\{
\begin{bmatrix} 
0 \\
0 \\
\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix} 
0 \\
1 \\
\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
0 \\
\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix} 
1 \\
1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\right\}
$$
such that, when concatenated, the second line is three times plus one the first line (in binary). I have to show that $L$ is regular by providing a $DFA$.

**What I know**: The technique is to think of $L^R$, the reverse language, provide it's $DFA$ and apply an algorithm (that I already know) and get to ${L^R}^R=L$.

**What I don't understand**: I found the $DFA$ that recognizes $L^R$, [image: Finite deterministic automaton that recognizes the reverse language of L],

but I don't understand it's functioning.

I appreciate any help, and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The three nodes above represents the carry-over of current multiplication.
$q_0$ particularly stands for the operation on the least significant bit since we have to plus 1 additionally. If the last digit is $[0,0]$, then we knows it cannot be right. Thus no transition from $q_0$ marked with $[0,0]$ can be found. If it is $[1, 0]$, then this digit is verified and the carry-over is $\displaystyle\frac{1*3+1}2=2$, which means that we will have to add an additional 2 when we check the next digit.

The other nodes perform alike. I shall leave it to you. The accepting state is that we have checked all the digits and the residual carry-over is $0$.

One more thing, $q_0$ can be replaced by the middle node above which is marked by $1$. Think about it if you successfully figure out why the current DFA works for $L^R$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. For example, why can't I verify $[1, 0]$ in state $10$?

Comment: If DFA encounters $[1,0]$ in state $10$, it won't accept the string whatever is left (A self-looped state is omitted in this DFA), because the current digit would be $(1*3+2) \% 2 = 1$. However, $0$ is given, and the string fails to meet the requirement.